# Two instances of same javascript class on one page refer to same instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am attempting to write a Countdown timer script, and it works with only one instance on the page, but if I add a second one, only the second starts counting.

I discovered that if I load both, but only call the start for the second one, the first one fires. It appears that they are not scoped correctly.

I'm using the new class syntax, so I thought it should work as is, but I'm obviously missing something. I'm hoping someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong. My primary language is PHP, and I am not as well versed in JS as I'd like to be.

Here is a link to my gist which contains the code: https://gist.github.com/kennyray/b35f4c6640be9539c5d16581de7714e0

```js
class CountdownTimer {

 constructor(minutesLabel = null, secondsLabel = null) {
  self = this;
  this.minutesLabel = minutesLabel;
  this.secondsLabel = secondsLabel;
  this.totalSeconds = (this.minutesLabel.textContent / 60) + this.secondsLabel.textContent;
  this.timer = null;
 }
 
 set minutesLabel(value) {
  self._minutesLabel = value;
 }
 
 set secondsLabel(value) {
  self._secondsLabel = value;
 }
 
 get minutesLabel() {
  return self._minutesLabel;
 }
 
 get secondsLabel() {
  return self._secondsLabel;
 }
 
 
    setTime() { 
      self.totalSeconds--;
   if (parseInt(self.minutesLabel.innerHTML) == 0 && parseInt(self.secondsLabel.innerHTML) == 0) { self.stopTimer; return;}
   
   if (self.secondsLabel.innerHTML.textContent < 0) { self.secondsLabel.innerHTML = 59 }
   if (self.minutesLabel.innerHTML.textContent < 0) { self.minutesLabel.innerHTML = 59 }
   self.secondsLabel.innerHTML = self.pad((self.totalSeconds % 60));
      self.minutesLabel.innerHTML = self.pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60));
   
    } 
    
 pad(val) {
      var valString = val + "";
        if (valString.length < 2) {
            return "0" + valString;
  } else {
            return valString;
        } 
    }
    
    resetTimer() {
        clearInterval(self.timer);
        self.totalSeconds = 0;
        self.secondsLabel.innerHTML = self.pad(self.totalSeconds % 60);
        self.minutesLabel.innerHTML = self.pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds / 60));   
    }
    
    startTimer() {
     self.timer = setInterval(self.setTime, 1000);
    }
 
 stopTimer() {
     clearInterval(self.timer);
    }

}

const t1 = new CountdownTimer(document.getElementById("minutes1"), document.getElementById("seconds1"));
t1.startTimer();


const t2 = new CountdownTimer(document.getElementById("minutes"), document.getElementById("seconds"));
console.log(t1.startTimer() === t2.startTimer());
t2.startTimer();
```

```html
<label id="minutes1">01</label>:<label id="seconds1">10</label>
<br>
<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">10</label>
```

Comment: Better to have the code inline in your question than to ask people to go offsite. More chance of getting an answer. Ive done it for you. But I note it doesnt exhibit the bahaviour your describe.

Comment: Thanks! Was about to go do it when I saw your comment.

Comment: After taking out the `self = this`, you will want to bind your setTime, .-. `setInterval(this.setTime.bind(this), 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a global variable `self` (why the hell do you do this?) that get's overiden. Just use `this` in a class.

Your startTimer function then needs to be

```
 startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.setTime.bind(this), 1000);
  }
```

and should maybe check if there's already an interval and clear `this.timer` completely

```
startTimer() {
    if (this.timer) this.stopTimer();
    this.timer = setInterval(this.setTime.bind(this), 1000);
}

stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
}
```

Comment: Oops! I definitely know better than that!

Comment: I just updated my gist with the modification you mentioned. I changed all self. to this. and updated the startTimer function. They're still referring to each other though. Would you mind taking a look at my changes and see if I missed something else?

Comment: They are not referring to each other any more. @Kenny What makes you think they are?

Comment: The second counter is decreasing by 2 instead of 1.  And this line is producing true in the console log: console.log(t1.startTimer() === t2.startTimer());  @bambam

Comment: Sure it does. You have to remove the line. With this line you are: **1)** starting t1 and t2; **2)** starting t2 a second time, making the interval be doubled. (Actually you start t2 a second time a line thereafter, causing the 2 seconds decrease) ... You can check if the timeout exists in `startTimer`, and clear it if so. The reason for your `t1.startTimer() === t2.startTimer() // true` is that `undefined === undefined // true`, since `startTimer` returns nothing - so undefined

Comment: I don’t know what to say on that one. #facepalm. Thanks again. Lol

Answer (score 2):

It really boils down to this line

```
self = this;
```

By not including the keyword `var` you elevate that to global scope. If you want to use `self` instead of `this` in the ctor (which is perfectly fine) just prefix it with `var`:

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: Doh! I know better than that! Thank you for pointing that out!